# Windows server security setup (firewalls, SQL server and other points)

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, security, vpn, firewall

Firstly apologies for this being a non-specific question, I'm not really sure where to look for specifics so this is a general discussion of regular issues I'm faced with. I'm going round in circles trying to work with a number of different hosts and their enforced "best practices". I'd like to try and garner some knowledge for myself based around the following statements.

*"Using the default SQL server port is less secure than using a random non-standard port"*
 - this seems to me like security through obscurity which isn't particularly secure?

*"Firewalls that offer packet inspection do not need to worry about having a totally open port"*
 - is it okay to have a completely open inbound port (e.g. in this instance sql) as the security aspect is handled by packet inspection?

*"Adding IP based firewall restrictions is not secure due to IP sniffing/spoofing - the correct/best way is to use a VPN between machines."*
 - this obviously isn't always possible but on server<>server tasks should a VPN be used?

This is drawn from my confusion from having to deal with inheriting the following setups:

HOST A
- hardware firewall all outbound traffic open
- I can manage the inbound traffic by opening ports globally or by IP
- Currently no VPN

HOST B
- hardware firewall I have no control over
- 3 outbound ports open (very restrictive) not able to open any more
- SQL port inbound is completely open which I can restrict using windows firewall
- Currently no VPN

HOST C
- no hardware firewall
- Windows firewall I can manage if needed
- SQL setup to use non-default port
- Currently no VPN

I need these servers to be able to communicate on several different ports which server B does not allow for. To me a VPN between them all looks to be the right approach but am very unfamiliar with this so open to being corrected?

Answer (score 1):

This is a broad question, but I will address the main issues

> "Using the default SQL server port is
>   less secure than using a random
>   non-standard port"
>   - this seems to me like security through obscurity which isn't
>   particularly secure?

You are correct. having non default ports as a security measure is overrated. However, it does add some security against simple attacks.
If some one want to break into the system, this wouldn't stop him. but if someone (or some thousands) bored hackers run port scanners to look for a SQL server (or any other server) to practice or fool around, a non default port may stop them.

> "Firewalls that offer packet
>   inspection do not need to worry about
>   having a totally open port"
>   - is it okay to have a completely open inbound port (e.g. in this instance
>   sql) as the security aspect is handled
>   by packet inspection?

Packet inspection is higher level and more complex then port blocking - and therefor it's more susceptible for attacks, bus, or configuration errors.
Generally you should place security measures in the lowest level appropriate, so if port blocking is an option, it will be better then packet inspection

> "Adding IP based firewall restrictions
>   is not secure due to IP
>   sniffing/spoofing - the correct/best
>   way is to use a VPN between machines."
>   - this obviously isn't always possible but on server<>server tasks should a
>   VPN be used?

It's true that you can trust IP addresses outside you network as a strong security measure, and VPN will be a more suitable solution.
However, assuming the attacker doesn't have control over your ISP or network access equipment, spoofing an IP isn't very simple

Comment: Thanks for the reply, as with Gregs answer I'm unable to upvote at present but your comments are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

SQL is very secure over the internet - if you use a certificate and transport encryption.  Not doing so is a security "worst practice", unless using a site-site VPN.  Enabling and using transport encryption is not difficult, and enables access without the need for a site-site VPN.

> "Adding IP based firewall restrictions
>   is not secure due to IP
>   sniffing/spoofing - the correct/best
>   way is to use a VPN between machines."

To be more specific, sending unencrypted data over that type of connection is insecure.  If the data and authentication are encrypted, there are legitimate scenarios for ip restrictions.

Comment: Thanks Greg, just tried to upvote the answer but an unable to at present because I don't have enough rep. I guess the cert route is the appropriate action for all open services not just SQL Server?

Comment: It depends on the product.  In this case, there is very good built-in support for certificate based authentication and encryption.  A regular ftp server cannot, but an sftp server should work.